# ¿como hacer que un Bitmap se pueda leer como ruta?

Tags: java, android-studio

```
Hash_file_maps = new HashMap<String, String>();


    sliderLayout = (SliderLayout)findViewById(R.id.slider);

  for (int i=0;i<NombreImagen.length;i++)
   {
        Hash_file_maps.put(NombreImagen[i],imagenes[i]);

    }

for(String name : Hash_file_maps.keySet()){

        TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(MainActivity.this);
        textSliderView
                .description(name)
                .image(Hash_file_maps.get(name))
                .image()

                .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                .setOnSliderClickListener(this);
        textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
        textSliderView.getBundle()
                .putString("extra",name);
        sliderLayout.addSlider(textSliderView);
    }
```

el .image() me esta pidiendo una ruta pero en mi caso tengo BitMaps

Answer (score 0):

Si revisas el [ejemplo](https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/blob/master/demo%2Fsrc%2Fmain%2Fjava%2Fcom%2Fdaimajia%2Fslider%2Fdemo%2FMainActivity.java), el método `image()` indica que necesita in valor int del recurso en tu programa, para cargar la imagen. Para cargar varias imagenes se crea un  `Hashmap` donde se define el nombre y el id del o los recursos:

```
  HashMap<String,Integer> file_maps = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        file_maps.put("Imagen Uriel",R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        file_maps.put("otra imagen",R.drawable.bigbang);
```

De esa forma cargaría la(s) imagen(es)sin problema:

```
 textSliderView
                .description(name)
                .image(file_maps.get(name))
                //.image() // * No necesaria.
                .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                .setOnSliderClickListener(this);
```

la segunda llamada al método `.image()` que estas agregando es innecesaria.