# ¿Cómo hacer que lea bitmap mi carrusel de imágenes?

Tags: java, android-studio

```
for(String name : Hash_file_maps.keySet()){

            TextSliderView textSliderView = new TextSliderView(MainActivity.this);
            textSliderView
                    .description(name)
                    .image()
                    .setScaleType(BaseSliderView.ScaleType.Fit)
                    .setOnSliderClickListener(this);
            textSliderView.bundle(new Bundle());
            textSliderView.getBundle()
                    .putString("extra",name);
            sliderLayout.addSlider(textSliderView);
        }
       // sliderLayout.setPresetTransformer(SliderLayout.Transformer.A);
        sliderLayout.setPresetIndicator(SliderLayout.PresetIndicators.Center_Bottom);
        sliderLayout.setCustomAnimation(new DescriptionAnimation());
        sliderLayout.setDuration(2000);
        sliderLayout.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    }
```

el `.image()` me pide un `url` pero en mi caso tengo un mapa de bits, y no se como mostrar mis imágenes en el carrusel.

Comment: utilizo un Hash_file_maps

Comment: Hash_file_maps  es HashMap que contiene las url. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/78588/como-hacer-que-un-bitmap-se-pueda-leer-como-ruta/78736#78736  puedes convertir esta imagen a bitmap pero el método solo acepta una url, ya revisaste esto?

Comment: ¿Que tiene que ver este problema con la etiqueta 'android-studio'?

Answer (score 0):

Para cargar una imagen se usa el método .image() dentro de este el parámetro necesario es precisamente una url.

Si estas usando la clase `TextSliderView` , tendrías que realizar tu mismo la implementación.

De hecho ya se ha requerido esto..
https://github.com/daimajia/AndroidImageSlider/issues/130

pero no se ha agregado, entonces como solución es modificar la clase `BaseSlider` para que puedas asignar al método `image()` un bitmap :

```
package com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderTypes;

import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.daimajia.slider.library.R;
import com.squareup.picasso.Callback;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;
import com.squareup.picasso.RequestCreator;

import java.io.File;

/**

When you want to make your own slider view, you must extends from this class.

BaseSliderView provides some useful methods.

I provide two example: {@link com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderTypes.DefaultSliderView} and

{@link com.daimajia.slider.library.SliderTypes.TextSliderView}

if you want to show progressbar, you just need to set a progressbar id as @+id/loading_bar.
*/
public abstract class BaseSliderView {

protected Context mContext;

private Bundle mBundle;

/**

Error place holder image.
*/
private int mErrorPlaceHolderRes;
/**

Empty imageView placeholder.
*/
private int mEmptyPlaceHolderRes;
private String mUrl;
private File mFile;
private int mRes;
private Bitmap mBitmap;

protected OnSliderClickListener mOnSliderClickListener;

private boolean mErrorDisappear;

private ImageLoadListener mLoadListener;

private String mDescription;

/**

Scale type of the image.
*/
private ScaleType mScaleType = ScaleType.Fit;
public enum ScaleType{
CenterCrop, CenterInside, Fit, FitCenterCrop
}

protected BaseSliderView(Context context) {
mContext = context;
this.mBundle = new Bundle();
}

/**

the placeholder image when loading image from url or file.
@Param resId Image resource id
@return
*/
public BaseSliderView empty(int resId){
mEmptyPlaceHolderRes = resId;
return this;
}
/**

determine whether remove the image which failed to download or load from file
@Param disappear
@return
*/
public BaseSliderView errorDisappear(boolean disappear){
mErrorDisappear = disappear;
return this;
}
/**

if you set errorDisappear false, this will set a error placeholder image.
@Param resId image resource id
@return
*/
public BaseSliderView error(int resId){
mErrorPlaceHolderRes = resId;
return this;
}
/**

the description of a slider image.
@Param description
@return
*/
public BaseSliderView description(String description){
mDescription = description;
return this;
}
/**

set a url as a image that preparing to load
@Param url
@return
*/
public BaseSliderView image(String url){
if(mFile != null || mRes != 0 || mBitmap != null){
throw new IllegalStateException("Call multi image function," +
"you only have permission to call it once");
}
mUrl = url;
return this;
}
/**

set a file as a image that will to load
@Param file
@return
*/
public BaseSliderView image(File file){
if(mUrl != null || mRes != 0 || mBitmap != null){
throw new IllegalStateException("Call multi image function," +
"you only have permission to call it once");
}
mFile = file;
return this;
}
public BaseSliderView image(int res){
if(mUrl != null || mFile != null || mBitmap != null){
throw new IllegalStateException("Call multi image function," +
"you only have permission to call it once");
}
mRes = res;
return this;
}

public BaseSliderView image(Bitmap bitmap){
if(mUrl != null || mFile != null || mBitmap != null){
throw new IllegalStateException("Call multi image function," +
"you only have permission to call it once");
}
mBitmap = bitmap;
return this;
}

public String getUrl(){
return mUrl;
}

public boolean isErrorDisappear(){
return mErrorDisappear;
}

public int getEmpty(){
return mEmptyPlaceHolderRes;
}

public int getError(){
return mErrorPlaceHolderRes;
}

public String getDescription(){
return mDescription;
}

public Context getContext(){
return mContext;
}

/**

set a slider image click listener
@Param l
@return
*/
public BaseSliderView setOnSliderClickListener(OnSliderClickListener l){
mOnSliderClickListener = l;
return this;
}
/**

When you want to implement your own slider view, please call this method in the end in getView() method

@Param v the whole view

@Param targetImageView where to place image
*/
protected void bindEventAndShow(final View v, ImageView targetImageView){
final BaseSliderView me = this;

v.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@override
public void onClick(View v) {
if(mOnSliderClickListener != null){
mOnSliderClickListener.onSliderClick(me);
}
}
});

mLoadListener.onStart(me);

Picasso p = Picasso.with(mContext);
RequestCreator rq = null;
if(mUrl!=null){
rq = p.load(mUrl);
}else if(mFile != null){
rq = p.load(mFile);
}else if(mBitmap != null){
targetImageView.setImageBitmap(mBitmap);
if(v.findViewById(R.id.loading_bar) != null){
v.findViewById(R.id.loading_bar).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
}else if(mRes != 0){
rq = p.load(mRes);
}else{
return;
}

if(rq == null){
return;
}

if(getEmpty() != 0){
rq.placeholder(getEmpty());
}

if(getError() != 0){
rq.error(getError());
}

switch (mScaleType){
case Fit:
rq.fit();
break;
case CenterCrop:
rq.fit().centerCrop();
break;
case CenterInside:
rq.fit().centerInside();
break;
}

rq.into(targetImageView,new Callback() {
@override
public void onSuccess() {
if(v.findViewById(R.id.loading_bar) != null){
v.findViewById(R.id.loading_bar).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
}
}

@Override
public void onError() {
    if(mLoadListener != null){
        mLoadListener.onEnd(false,me);
    }
}
});
}

public BaseSliderView setScaleType(ScaleType type){
mScaleType = type;
return this;
}

public ScaleType getScaleType(){
return mScaleType;
}

/**

the extended class have to implement getView(), which is called by the adapter,
every extended class response to render their own view.
@return
*/
public abstract View getView();
/**

set a listener to get a message , if load error.
@Param l
*/
public void setOnImageLoadListener(ImageLoadListener l){
mLoadListener = l;
}
public interface OnSliderClickListener {
public void onSliderClick(BaseSliderView slider);
}

/**

when you have some extra information, please put it in this bundle.
@return
*/
public Bundle getBundle(){
return mBundle;
}
public interface ImageLoadListener{
public void onStart(BaseSliderView target);
public void onEnd(boolean result,BaseSliderView target);
}

}
```

Comment: ya vi gracias, pero como llamo a la clase y la utilizo en vez de mi codigo

Comment: cree un nueva clase con el codigo que me mandaste @Jorgesys llamada Carrucel, pero al momento de enviarle sliderLayout.addSlider(car); no me funciona me da error, ayuda xfavor, es que soy estudiante